# Check if MySQL state is right or not programmatically?

Tags: c#, mysql

In my project, I want to check whether MySQL state syntax is right or not with C#, how  to do this, does MySQL has a API that could let me to check the state syntax.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You could try this website [MySQL Syntax Check](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/), if you want to purely check SQL syntax. If you want to test whether the syntax works for your specific database/query, you'll need to create a test database/table and test it using that.

Comment: I am using C# , in my project, I need to check it programly with C#. so does it could  be implemented?

Comment: Well, you could either post part/all of the mysql here, I'm sure we can help verify if it has correct syntax (if it contains sensitive info, change it), or in C# you could use the [try/catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) to check if there are any errors (you would still need to run the code and execute the sql once to check if it works, try a test statement first).

Comment: Are you creating your own workbench?

Comment: whether has any other solution except try/catch, I am developing Winform Project.

Comment: I I want to check a insert syntax, if custom typed correct then the data has been inserted successfully. this is not my except.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) to do this. By either throwing an error or not, it will tell you if the sql syntax is correct, is supported by that exact server version, and even if the involved tables and columns exist, which is more than a pure syntax verification can do.

However, assuming from your comments you are actually trying to tell if your code will (or did) successfully insert (all) rows, and this will not work this way: merely validating the syntax will not verify that the data you are tyring to insert is valid. Even if the statement is correct, you could be trying to insert a `string` or `float` value into an `integer` column or multiplying `string` columns. Or you could violate constraints, e.g. inserting `null` into a column that is declared `not null` or violate a foreign key or unique key constraint. And it can also depend on the server configuration; e.g. inserting the date `0000-00-00` might be allowed or not, and invalid data might result in an error on one server and just a warning on another.

So if you actually want to check if an `insert` statement inserted rows (and in that case it's usually a good idea to ask that instead of asking a completely different question), you can simply use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx). It will return

> The number of rows affected.

In simple cases, this will be the number of inserted rows. If you are using e.g. triggers or `on duplicate key update`, it will include their effect, but usually, you don't even require the exact value anyway, and will only check that it is `> 0`. On the other hand, not every `insert` statement has to insert rows to be correct; e.g. a query that shall insert missing rows based on some critera obviously did a good job even if it didn't insert a single row just because no row is missing.

So if you have to execute completely unknown code, this is the way to go: simply execute the statement you want to execute, and handle any errors that might occur.

Although usually, you will not allow the user to enter any statement he wants. You might have some form where the user enters the data, where you can then validate the input before executing the (prepared) statement (e.g. checking if an integer is really an integer) or use data aware components (which might do database access and type validation on their own). If errors occur (e.g. a primary key already exists or a lost connection to the server), catch and handle it (e.g. display a userfriendly error message like "Sorry, the user you are inserting already exists").

If you really need to check a statement including data validation before you execute it, you could start a transaction, use `ExecuteNonQuery`, roll it back and evaluate the result/error. But keep in mind that the result might not be the same at a different point in time - after you tested it, someone else might have e.g. inserted or deleted a row with the the primary key you are trying to insert.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you answer help me come up other different ideas. Thank you very much.